# Merge several reports / have several report chapters

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I **merge** or concatenate several jrxml jasperreports into one report unit,

**without using java code**?

I can upload jrxml files and generate report units with the REST API / Webservice **only**.

Or is there any **other solution** for this element layout?

```
--header--
* group of countries
    england
    australia
    croatia
* pie chart with countries
--footer--

--new page--

--header--
* group of something else
    something 1
    something else 2
    ....
* chart of something else
--footer--
```

I think of having an Array variable which I iterate over with a `<group>` Element and print a Sub report for each Element. Like:

```
<variable name="chapters" class="java.util.List" resetType="None" resetGroup="ChapterGroup" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="BrowserGroup">
    <variableExpression>
        <![CDATA[java.util.Arrays.asList("browser", "country")]]>           
    </variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression>
        <![CDATA[new java.util.ArrayList()]]>
    </initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<group name="ChapterGroup" isStartNewPage="true" keepTogether="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{chapters}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
  <subreport>
    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="325" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
    <subreportParameter name="<![CDATA[$V{chapters}]]>">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{chapters}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA["repo:/reports/" + $V{chapters}]]></subreportExpression>
  </subreport>
```

But I can't get it to work..

Using Jasper Report server 5, (I code the jrxml myself, and only use iReports for preview).
Same datasource for everything, two queries for 2 grouping sections with charts.

Comment: what about having sub-reports ??

Comment: ..that's is the question. How to use them without Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding Report Groups, you can add as many report groups as you want per chart and keep the header and footer in the same report group for every chart and every Report Group will have Sub Dataset.
I have combined 5 report with different header and footer.

You can see the sample report provided by JasperSoft name " Standard Chart Report" under Reports directory.

To do this :-
1:- Add dataset 
2:- Add Report Group
3:- Drag a chart from palette

Here is the code sample, In this code sample i am combining Bar chart and Stacked Bar chart in two pages with two different sub dataset :-

```
    <group name="bar">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="400">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="300"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["Bar Chart"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle>
                        <subtitleExpression><![CDATA["Chart Displaying Bars"]]></subtitleExpression>
                    </chartSubtitle>
                    <chartLegend/>
                    <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Bar Chart"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="salesState">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="categoryDataset"/>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{sales_state}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{full_name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{personAmount}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Name"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Amount"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
<group name="stackedBar">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="400">
            <stackedBarChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="300"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA["Stacked Bar Chart"]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle>
                        <subtitleExpression><![CDATA["Chart Displaying Stacked Bars"]]></subtitleExpression>
                    </chartSubtitle>
                    <chartLegend/>
                    <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Stacked Bar Chart"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="salesState">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="categoryDataset"/>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{sales_state}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{full_name}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{personAmount}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Name"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Amount"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Comment: So when you know how to combine reports, why don't you show me how or fix my attempt?

Comment: Open the sample report "Sample Chart Report" in iReport, there you can see the structure.

Comment: Your answer could be way better, it did not really help me nor is it going to help anyone else that much. The only useful hint was looking into the sample report.

Comment: I Have updated the answer, Let me know if still you are facing any problem.

Comment: The biggest problem for me was to identify where I put `<title/>`, `<pageHeader/>` and `<pageFooter/>` after having defined several groups. I now know they just go after the groups and everything works fine. Your answer looks better now too!

Comment: You dont need to add these bands to have <title>, <pageHeader/> and <pageFooter/> for every group , use the same space to add <title>, <pageHeader/> and <pageFooter/> without adding these bands.